# Html.PasswordFor get auto filled with value of preceding textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

In my change-passsword form, there are these fields:

```
 <dt>Old Password</dt>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user_ID, new { style = "width:200px;margin-top:-4px;", maxlength = 25 })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_ID)

        <dt>Old Password</dt>
        <dd>

              @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.txtOldPassword, new { style = "width:200px;margin-top:-4px;", maxlength = 10, @class = "smallcase",autocomplete = "off"  })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.txtOldPassword)

        </dd>

   ..........................
```

Each time the form is loaded or the `userid` field is edited, The password field gets autofilled with the userid. When I use `@Html.TextBoxFor()`, the problem is fixed. Why this happens? I have to use `@Html.textBoxFor()`. As you can see in the code, I tried turning `autocomplete` off. But failed.

Comment: Send us your controller's action method as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try it in a different browser. I think your browser is caching the username and password forms. I know Chrome does this for me sometimes. When you are sure the oldPassword field on the model is not set, it is probably a browser problem.